# SCRIPT - Multiple programs in multiple terminals

Tags: bash, shell, loops, execution, gnome-terminal

I made a script so I can easily execute multiple programs in different terminals by just writing

```
./script.sh (numberofprogramstype1) (numberofprogramstype2)
```

The problem is it only executes one of each type, even though I am looping it based on the arguments given. Here is my code:

```
gcc program1.c -lpthread

for i in {1..$1}
do
       gnome-terminal -e ./a.out
done

gcc program2.c -lpthread

for i in {1..$2}
do
        gnome-terminal -e ./a.out
done
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace expansion happens before parameter expansion; you can only use hard-coded numbers in them. Use a C-style `for` loop instead.

```
# {1..$1}
for ((i=1;i<=$1;i++)); do
   ...
```